# Dell Overlays - Ubuntu to Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, dell, configuration

If I wish to change the Ubuntu DE in a Dell laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 to Kubuntu, I should be able to do so with:
`sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

If I then use the command
`sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`
to remove Ubiquity will I also then lose all the Dell configurations/overlays or will these remain?

Thanks.

Comment: So this is a Dell with Ubuntu pre-installed? If so, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042108/is-dell-pre-installed-ubuntu-the-same-as-the-general-release

Comment: This is a Dell pre-installed. Your linked article refers to upgrading to 18.04 and to doing a fresh install of a non-Dell iso. My question relates to changing flavour while keeping all the built in Dell overlays.

Comment: You can have multiple DEs installed.  `autoremove` will not remove the other DE unless you tell it to remove it.  However, some DEs can conflict with each other and might cause some system performance problems, especially some of the heavier DEs.  But sometimes you just have to try.

Comment: Thanks Terrance. Want I really want to know is, if I install the plasma DE on my Dell laptop pre-installed with Ubuntu, can I be assured that if I then remove the Ubiquity DE that I will still have all the  built in Dell overlays & configurations and that they will not be removed also.

Comment: The thing is, I don't know how they set it up, so I would be the wrong person to ask.  Sorry about that.