# 7390 XPS 13 Dev edition- Dedicated ubuntu drivers

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, dell, xps, 19.10

I recently got the new 2019 XPS 13 dev edition. the Only "issue" I have is that it comes with ubuntu 18.04. before moving to ubuntu 19.10 (or Kubuntu) I was wondering if there is anything specific on the ubuntu version Dell is using. 
So Far everything is working like a charm, and I wouldn't want to break things while upgrading ;)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am also interested in this question. Soon I will receive my XPS 13 7390 dev edition with Ubuntu 18.04 pre-installed, and I might want to upgrade to 19.10. Please let me know if you find anything.

Comment: didn't find anything, I did the upgrade to 19.04 (almost) no issues just add to munually add the wifi driver. asite from that little niggle all great, super happy. I was thinking to move back to arch, but I am now concidering staying on the ubutu. pondering a move to KDE though :)

Comment: Same question but 18.04 on XPS 13 9370. I ended using Kubuntu, very happy indeed. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042108/is-dell-pre-installed-ubuntu-the-same-as-the-general-release

Comment: Note that it needs several settings changed: Ubuntu 19.10 Provides Good Out-Of-The-Box Support For The Dell XPS 7390 Icelake Laptop
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=dell-xps7390-ubuntu1910&num=1
Typically it is best to use LTS version of Ubuntu until next LTS version 20.04 comes out. And if you want to test a non-LTS version, just create a 25 or 30GB / (root) partition and install it as dual boot. I would not share /home, but you can share a data partition or two.

Answer (score 1):

I tried updating my XPS 7390 last night. The process is not ideal and I ended up reverting to 18.04 (for now). The primary issues were:

1. Wifi driver isn't present so you have no internet. You can overcome this by downloading the driver and installing it manually. I used the instructions [here](https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/killer-ax1650-in-debian-ubuntu-16-04/).
2. The display looks like it needs a driver because the screen quality wasn't as good. I gave up while investigating so I didn't full track that down.
3. The Dell apt repos won't work any more. I assumed (maybe incorrectly) that because of that that all this custom stuff will now have to be manually updated for a while. I'd love to know if I'm wrong there and it can just be re-enabled.
4. After all that I got worried that I'd have to fish to see if other bits and pieces were missing and, as this is my daily driver, I was worried something wouldn't work at a critical moment so I reverted.

I really hope someone can publish a full accounting of what's missing and how to do it properly one day (maybe Dell). I'd love to but I just don't know exactly what the steps are.

If you update, let us know somehow!

Comment: How exactly did you "revert" to 18.04? You did a clean install of 18.04 and it worked fine?

Comment: Yeah. I backed up and used the recovery from the GRUB menu.

Comment: Ah so you used a backup from the pre-installed distro from Dell, right? Haven't tried a real clean install of 18.04.

Comment: Yep. Dell makes it pretty easy. You can also use a recovery USB drive. The GRUB one is easy enough assuming you haven't blown away the partition.